# What is the purpose of UFC fighters extending and retracting their lead hand? Why don't boxers do so, at least as much?

Tags: boxing, ufc

Based on my extensive experience watching some UFC fights on YouTube, this hand movement seems very common. All I can think of is it at least partially to keep the limbs moving and making it easier to make sudden movements, while getting the the opponent a bit desensitized to hands coming towards their faces.

Follow-up - so why don't boxers seem to do this as much?

Comment: This extending hand technique was overly used a lot throughout the Valentina vs Amanda fight #2 by Amanda Nunes, and as far as I know, she was not deducted any points, even after a warning early in the fight. This adds another “ fishy” element to this fight. Why has this been overlooked. Amanda was more in a defense mode way too much in the fight, and allowed to use a defensive extra ( at least semi - cheating) move? I do not agree that on that occasion Amanda won. Compare this to Valentina’s cautious but still very energetic win against Liz Carmouche. It’s understandable to adjust to your opp

Comment: @mattm: Just letting you know, not all of the answer was converted to the comment.

Comment: @MacacoBranco - Yes, the comment field has a character limit. As it's basically a well disguised rant about Nunes winning, I think we are ok with it. It technically doesn't even work as a comment, but...

Comment: The beginning is useful as a pointer to an example. I don't think the entire post adds much.

Answer (score 4):

This is not my area of expertise, but there's a fairly lengthy exploration of it [here](https://forums.sherdog.com/threads/keeping-lead-hand-in-sticking-out-in-front.3525925/). Some of the reasons:

> You use the arm as a antenna. as long as the opponent are outside of your reach you are safe. The oppnent have to lauch his attacks from slightly longer range than he is used to and it drives them insane. Sometimes I just move out of the way when they try to go in, sometimes I keep the arm rigid and use bodyweight shift to meet them half way and push them off ballance. sometimes, once the opponet has understood that they need to get inside the arm length to attack, I move the shoulder back and shorten the distance without them noticing it, and then launch an attack when they think they are safe.It is a very defensive stance.
>
> Opponents tend to be frustrated and become focused on he hand as they cannot grasp that it really is not a threat in itself, and that you really give upp that hand as a effective offensive weapon. It is weak against good kickers (especially front kicks/teeps).

....

> Plenty of fighters use it, it can obstruct the opponent's view, it can check their jab (assuming southpaw) and so on. It's also very common in Muay Thai which tends to have a longer guard than boxing. I've used it pretty much for as long as I've been training and I was taught with it - and honestly I've never had any problems, you've just got to understand WHY you use it - as opposed to just doing it because you've seen other fighters do it.

You move it in and out because, well, keeping any limb outstretched is practically begging for it to be struck or grappled. You don't see this as much in boxing because boxing tends to be an arm-reach sport while MMA has closer (grappling) and further (kicking) ranges to worry about, making gauging the distance all the more important. Also, if you're within striking range, it may be illegal. Apparently, the term for this is "posting" and it's meant to refer to pushing your opponent away or stiff-arming them instead of punching them, but it basically makes an extended arm potentially illegal if within range.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks Sean.

Comment: @AmorphousBlob: Not at all. :) I learned something in the process of reading up on it myself.

Comment: Look at Judo, e. g. in Doha right now.

In Boxing you can't be pulled and thrown as in in UFC or Judo.
Here you use it for distance checking and for testing of resistance and answering moves of your opponent. If there is a week point open, go for it.
Do it constantly, so you aren't messaging.